# Disable mat-datepicker with holidays list and weekdays(saturday & Sunday) in angular material

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I am trying to disable the dates based on list of holidays (Getting from api), and also I want to disable weekdays i.e Saturday and Sunday. I am able to disable list of holidays date, but can't able to disable the weekdays. Here is my code that I have used.

<input matInput [matDatepickerFilter]="holidayDateFilter" [matDatepicker]="picker">

```
holidayDateFilter = (d: Date): boolean => {
let d = moment(d);
if (this.holidayList) {
  return !this.holidayList.find((x) => {
    return moment(x).isSame(d, 'day');
  })
}
```

}

Now, where to I put condition for disabling weekends.

Please help me with this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add functionality to check if the day is weekend.

```
holidayDateFilter = (d: Date): boolean => {
  // check if date is weekend day
  if (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6) {
    return true;
  }

  // check if date is holiday
  let d = moment(d);
  if (this.holidayList) {
    return !this.holidayList.find(x => {
      return moment(x).isSame(d, 'day');
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Now, I have to do here is.
I have a string like this 'CXXXXXC', where C indicate Sunday and Saturday is Holiday for all.
I have another array holiday list ['date1', 'date2'.... so on]. this array of date can also contain Saturday and Sunday.

Comment: How to implement functionality for disabling weekend, when 'CXXXXXX' is coming in string and in holidayList some dates are of Saturday.

Comment: if (weekday === 0 || weekday === 6) {
      if(this.saturday && this.sunday){
        return weekday !== 0 && weekday !== 6;
      }
      else if(this.sunday){
        return weekday !== 0 ;
      } else if(this.saturday){
        return weekday !== 6;
      } else{
        return true;
      }
    }
    if (this.holidayList) {
      return !this.holidayList.find((x) => {
        let holidayDates = moment(x).isSame(momentDate, 'day');
        if(holidayDates){
          return moment(x).isSame(momentDate, 'day');
        }
      })
    }

Comment: Can anyone please help on this.